# Creating thread safe timed queue in C for *nix

Tags: c, linux, algorithm, queue

One part of my program creates some kind of messages. These messages are then processed in the second part.

I need some kind of timed queue between parts of my program that can keep messages in memory X seconds. X don't change while this timed queue exists.

Ideally this should look like this:

```
tqueue_t *tqueue_new(int seconds);
int tqueue_push(tqueue_t *queue, void *msg);
void *tqueue_pop(tqueue_t *queue);
```

`tqueue_pop()` should block and return when first message was in queue for X seconds.

What is the best way to do this? Maybe there are some already existing solutions?

Language: C

OS: *nix

*Also, this queue should work in threaded evironment.*

Comment: Maybe you can use a glib event loop and timed call-backs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to build this on top of [POSIX Message Queues](http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview) and let it take care of most of the details.  Something like:

(1) write queue with a time stamp field

(2) In your other thread either block on [mq_receive()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mq_receive) until a message comes in (or use [mq_notify()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mq_notify) to signal or create the thread for you).

(3) Read the queue and check the time stamp.

(4) Calculate the time difference for how long you have to wait and use [select()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/select) or some sleep/timer mechanism.

(5) Process the message.

Comment: Thank you. Take message and just wait is brilliant.